# valgrind find memory leak after call evtimer_del from libevent

Tags: c++, valgrind, libevent

I just create a new event with event_new(),
and finally del it with evtimer_del().
Then valgrind warning me there is memory leak(128 bytes in 1 blocks).
What do I missed?

The code:

```
evthread_use_pthreads();
auto _base = event_base_new();
event_init();
event* _timer = event_new(_base, -1, EV_TIMEOUT, NULL, NULL);
evtimer_del(_timer);
event_base_free(_base);
```

[image]

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to post text as image.

Comment: I put the code in text, sorry for that I just wanna put more info by image .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong deallocation function, from [docs](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-2.0/doxygen/html/event_8h.html#ab9a66f828d205eda84b321e32014cbbd):

> **event_new()**
>   Returns
>   a newly allocated struct event that must later be freed with `event_free()`.

While `evtimer_del` is an alias for `event_del()` which only unlists event.